# allowing datepickers to enter dates without seperators

Tags: c#, winforms, datepicker

I have a winform application. I need to write code in such a way that all the datepickers across the application accept dates without any seperators like /,- etc.
Is this feasible? If yes,how do I do it?

I do not want to create a custom control as that would mean changing the code at many places.

Answer (score 1):

Two possible paths that I can think of from the top of my head:

1. Use [MaskedTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It allows users to skip typing separators. But this approach will take away the calendar functionality from the users. See if that is fine in your scenario.
2. Create your own control. It is not all that hard at all. You simply need to capture `KeyDown` and examine input key. You can incorporate a calendar control and a TextBox in your custom control to make your life easier.

Comment: Cant use custom controls as it would mean changing code at many places

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "yyyyMMdd";
```

Of course, you'll probably want the custom format to be a 'global' constant somewhere.

Or create a function that takes a DateTimePicker as an argument and formats them.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, but I gave up on dateformatpickers and went another direction. I did not need the visual calender, so I did what you are asking, but with a standard textbox control. I wrote a method that I run my textbox.Text through; it takes just about every semi-standard date separator, or NO separator at all and creates a standardized date output. The only catch is that I expected my users to enter 6 or 8 characters; I did not want to guess if `11199` was `01-11-1999` or `11-01-1999`

Here is the method

```
    public static string ExpandingDates(string _date)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_date))
        {
            return "";
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                _date = _date.Replace("\\", "-");
                _date = _date.Replace(",", "-");
                if (!_date.Contains(".") & !_date.Contains("/") & !_date.Contains("-"))
                {
                    if (_date.Length == 6)
                    {
                        _date = _date.Insert(2, "-").Insert(5, "-");
                    }
                    else if (_date.Length == 8)
                    {
                        _date = _date.Insert(2, "-").Insert(5, "-");
                    }
                }
                try
                {
                    _date = Convert.ToDateTime(_date).ToShortDateString();
                }
                catch { _date = ""; }

            }
            catch
            {
                _date = "";
            }
            return _date;
        }
    }
```

Here is how I implemented it.

```
private void txtPurDate_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        txtPurDate.Text = ExpandingDates(txtPurDate.Text);            
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is idea for your reference.

It is simply putting a small adapter to your picker any time you want to retrieve date/time. This adapter will convert any string format provided by user into a well-format string that acceptable by your picker using a template.
For example:

```
YourDatePicker.Date = dateAdapter.FormatBySlash("20140205","yyyymmdd")
```

Your adapter will implement a parser function that convert the string by given format into a string that datepicker can accept it, eg."yyyymmdd" to "yyyy/mm/dd", "yyyymmdd" to "yyyy-mm-dd",etc.

```
DateAdapter
{
    public string FormatBySlash(string inputDate, string inputFormat)
    {
        string year = //pick 4 digits year from inputDate where inputFormat at "yyyy"
        string month = //pick 2 digits month from inputDate where inputFormat at "mm"
        string day = //pick 2 last digits day from inputDate where inputFormat at "dd"
        return year + "/" + month + "/" + day 
    }

    //implementation for other format method...
}
```

In CSharp language, using DateTime class is totally enough. It can parse whatever string format into a valid date time as long as you provide a proper format template.